# A problem involving similar triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

I've just started learning about similar triangles, and I'm having trouble with the following problem:

> Let $T$ be the triangle $ABC$, as shown on the figure. Let $P$ be the
>   midpoint of $\bar{AB}$ and $Q$ the midpoint of $\bar{AC}$. If
>   $\bar{PQ}$ has length $5$ cm, find the length of $\bar{BC}$.

[image]

According to my book, we just have to note that triangle $ABC$ is the dilation by $2$ of triangle triangle $APQ$, and since $\bar{BC}$ is the side corresponding to $\bar{PQ}$, it follows that $\bar{BC}=10$ cm. However, I'm not satisfied with that answer at all. It hasn't been given to us that one triangle is a dilation of the other (the way I see it, that's precisely what we're trying to prove).

So I've drawn segment $\bar{AM}$ as on the figure below, and by use of Pythagoras' theorem and after some algebra I got the following equalities:

$$PQ=\sqrt{(AP)^2-(AN)^2}+\sqrt{(AQ)^2-(AN)^2}$$
$$BC=\sqrt{4(AP)^2-(AM)^2}+\sqrt{(4(AQ)^2-(AM)^2}$$

So basically I just need to show now that $\bar{AM}=2\bar{AN}$, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Would you agree that two triangles are similar if all the corresponding angles are congruent ?

Comment: Triangles $\triangle PAQ$ and $\triangle BAC$ are similar by the “SAS similarity criterion,” because two sides have lengths in the same ratio ($2:1$, because of the midpoints) and the angles between these sides are the same (they are both $\angle A$). Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the intercept theorems we get $$PQ=\frac{1}{2}BC$$